# Best way to mobilise a Wordpress website? (No plugins)

Tags: wordpress, mobile

We're just wondering what you guys think is the best way to optimise an existing website for mobile use (preferably, though not necessarily exclusively without the use of plugins).

Making the site responsive would be very difficult as the completed site has thousands of lines of CSS etc that would need to be changed, not to mention the structure changes that would be necessary.

If we were to set up a new site (say at m.xxxxxx.co.uk or xxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/m) would it be better to start from scrath or import the existing stuff and edit it. Then that raises the question of databases etc.

Anyway just wanting some opinions on the best way to do it from any Wordpress experts out there?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responsive design, or scaling elements of the site based on the available space. You are going to have to do the CSS all over anyway if you make a new site. Sounds like a good opportunity to clean up your styles.

Running two WordPress sites off of the same data presents a few issues that would be much more of a headache than the 'too much' CSS problem you have now.